# Why is $f^{(n)}(z)$ real when z is real for all $n$, if this is true for $n=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

In order to prove the Schwarz Reflection Principle using the Taylor expansion, we need the information that $f^{(n)}(z)$ is real if $z$ is real for all $n$. We have $f(z)$ real if $z$ is real, and that $f(z)$ is analytic over a region including the real axis. How do these imply that the $n^{th}$ derivative is also real?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z_0 \in \mathbb{R}$

$f'(z_0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z_0 + h) - f(z_0)}{h}$

If $f'$ exists, this limit must be the same if $h$ approaches from the real or imaginary axis, that said:

$f'(z_0) = \lim_{h\to 0\ h \in \mathbb{R}}  \frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h} \in \mathbb{R}$

$f^{(n)}$ follows the same reasoning.